# Webpack sass-loader fails to compile sass stylesheet imported into a react jsx document: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, sass-loader

I am using `Webpack 2.5.1`, `React 15.5.4`.

I am trying to use `Bootstrap` `_utilities.scss` in a react project. And
Webpack reports an error when I try to compile the document because it imports other sass partials using `@import` statement.

This is the code for my entry `main.jsx` document.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss' // this is what causes the error
import '../stylesheets/components/gallery.scss'; // this one compiles properly if I comment the _utilities.scss import statement. It does not use @import notation.

class Gallery extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return (<div id="gallery" className="d-flex p-2">
            <h1>using bootstrap flex-box</h1>
            <p>Something something something!</p>
            <button onClick={() => console.info('You clicked a button')}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

This is the code for my `webpack.config.js`.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CommonChunkPlugin = 
require('./node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: {
        main: './components/main.jsx',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('..', 'build', 'js'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CommonChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.js'
        })
    ]
};
```

As you can see, I am using `style-loader`, `css-loader`, and `sass-loader` to compile `css` and `scss` files.

This is the error message I get after running `Webpack`.

```
...  _utilities.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import "utilities/align";
| @import "utilities/background";  ...
```

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881675/webpack-2-sass-loader-unexpected-character) And this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058357/webpack2-not-understanding-import-statement-in-my-sass-files-how-to-compile-sa/42102403#42102403) but they don't help.

So, Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are excluding `node_modules` directory from as a target of SASS/CSS loaders, therefore Webpack won't be able to find a proper loader for any SASS file included from there.

Try to remove the `exclude` property from your SASS/CSS loaders settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need this plugin

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "main.css"
});
```

And then simply just put

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: extractPlugin.extract({
        use: ["css-loader","sass-loader"]
    })
}
```

And then in plugins you need this:

```
plugins:[extractPlugin]
```

Hope it helps